# I just want to output the products in the dashboard, In which the quantity is less than 10. It is connected in the firestore. How can I improve this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
{details.map((val, colorMap, prodName) => {
```

> This is where I'm a bit lost with its conditional statement

```
        if( colorMap < 10 ){
          return ( 
                  <ul>
                    <li key={prodName}><p className="pt-2">{val.prodName} </p></li>
                    <li><p className="pt-2">{}</p></li>
                  </ul>  
          );
        }
        return null;
```

Comment: `map`'s second argument is the index of the current element. What does your details array look like? Can you add an example to your question. It sounds like an array of objects in which case you probably meant to destructure each one: `({ val, colorMap, prodName })`.

Comment: Inside the firestore there is data called products in which inside the document consists of prodName the products name, colorMap which are the color of the products and its quantity. I want it to check the quantity of colors in the colorMap if its less than 10 it would output the following prodName with minimum color quantity. Btw I'm new to reactjs.

Answer (score 0):

there seems to be confusion there i guess, instead of destructuring in the `map` statement you are passing 3 arguments which is making it go wrong...

In the map statement do it this way:

```
function mapperRender() {
  details.map(({val, colorMap, prodName}) => {
     if( colorMap < 10 ){
          return ( 
                  <ul>
                    <li key={prodName}><p className="pt-2">{val.prodName} </p></li>
                    <li><p className="pt-2">{}</p></li>
                  </ul>  
          );
        }
        return null;
   }
}
```

and then in the jsx:

```
<div>
  {mapperRender()}
</div>
```

Comment: You're not returning the mapped array from that function. And `val.prodName` isn't right because `prodName` has already been destructured. And `map` wouldn't work either. It returns an array with the same length that it's processing. You should use `filter`.

Answer (score 0):

Initially you want to [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out those objects that have a `colorMap` value less that 10, and then you need to `map` over those filtered elements.

In this example I've added the data to state. I've then filtered the data, and used that data to create the list items.

```js
const { useState } = React;

// Pass in the data
function Example({ data }) {

  // Add the data to state
  const [ state, setState ] = useState(data);

  // `filter` all the objects where the
  // colorMap is less than 10 into a new array
  function getFiltered(data) {
    return data.filter(obj => {
      return obj.colorMap < 10;
    });
  }

  // Return an array of mapped JSX list items
  function createJSX(filtered) {
    return filtered.map(obj => {
      return <li key={obj.val}>{obj.prodName}</li>
    });
  }

  // `filter` the data in state...
  const filtered = getFiltered(state);

  // ...and use that to create the JSX
  return (
    <ul>{createJSX(filtered)}</ul>
  );

}

const data=[{val:1,colorMap:2,prodName:"Shoe"},{val:14,colorMap:14,prodName:"Bobby Davro"},{val:3,colorMap:3,prodName:"House"},{val:34,colorMap:34,prodName:"Barney"}];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example data={data} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Okay Thanks man, I'll try implementing this to my code.

Comment: @ImranNoir remember it's just a guide. It's how I personally write code. I like to separate things out. But I hoped it helped. The core message is `filter` then `map`.